# Setting context init parameter for jsf passthrough myfaces 2.0.15

Tags: jsf, myfaces, passthrough-elements

Im using myfaces verison 2.0.15. JSF passthrough is not working. I tried both namespaces:   `xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"` and `xmlns:pt="http://java.sun.com/jsf/passthrough"` and then `pt:aria-label="example`" on an `h:inputText` for example.

Both do not work. I get following error message: `No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.ENUM_CONVERTER_ALLOW_STRING_PASSTROUGH' found, using default value 'false'.`

It seems that I have to set a context init parameter, but I'm not able to find any valuable documentation for myfaces. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passtrough Attributes are new in JSF 2.2, so you need MyFaces 2.2.x